# Any need to manually dispose/close SPFile.openBinary method?

Tags: development

The following function copies the attachments from 1 list item to another, notice the  byte[] binFile = file.OpenBinary(); line, won't this keep an open hook on this file? Do I need to take some manual action to dispose this hook?

```
private static bool copyAttachments(string websiteURL, string src_List, int src_ID, string dest_List, int dest_ID)
        {
            using (SPSite Site = new SPSite(websiteURL))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = Site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList sourceList = web.Lists[src_List];
                    SPListItem sourceItem = sourceList.Items.GetItemById(src_ID);
                    SPList destList = web.Lists[dest_List];
                    SPListItem destItem = destList.Items.GetItemById(dest_ID);

                    SPFolder sourceItemAttachmentsFolder = sourceItem.Web.Folders["Lists"].SubFolders[sourceItem.ParentList.Title].SubFolders["Attachments"].SubFolders[sourceItem.ID.ToString()];

                    foreach (SPFile file in sourceItemAttachmentsFolder.Files)
                    {
                        byte[] binFile = file.OpenBinary();
                        destItem.Attachments.AddNow(file.Name, binFile);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to dispose when using OpenBinary. However, the stream that comes back from the `OpenBinaryStream` method will need to be disposed or you will run into problems very quickly.

I have written a post [about that particular scenario](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/07/solution-for-sharepoints-common.html).

Code for copying attachments can be found [in this post about synchronising two SharePoint lists](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/12/automatically-synchronise-sharepoint.html).

Answer (score 1):

The OpenBinary just gives you a copy of the binary contents of the SPFile, copied into the byte[] array. You do not need to dispose it, the GC takes care of it.